# How to edit the xorg.conf

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, cuda

My development environment Ubuntu14.04

I use Ubuntu 14.04 usb boot. When I installed CUDA7.0, the black screen appeared. But, I can enter the console mode.

so, I tried to edit the /etc/X11/xorg.conf. but, could not be edited in readonly.

I tried it with "sudo", "su", "su - " by vim. The results of "ls" , it is shown below.

```
#ls -ls

-rw-r--r-- root root
```

I can't understand that this file can't be edited by the root authority.

```
#lsof ｜grep xorg.conf

there is nothing.
```

and I tried with recovery mode, It was the same situation. Please advice somebody.

Comment: You need to create a xorg.conf manually, see my answer below!

Answer (score 2):

The xorg.conf does not exist by default any more. You CAN create one though.

Boot into recovery mode and select Root Shell. Then run:

```
X -configure
```

Then:

```
cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Reboot and you can edit the new Xorg.conf.

You don't even need to reboot, just do `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart`

Comment: If you see any error running `X -configure`, just ignore it!

Comment: Thanks. but I couldn't execute this code  "#cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf". → permission denied.

Comment: Don't thank me! ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey ☑ under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green. If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you really like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark and the little up-arrow... If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 1):

This is only a thought, but it sounds like your hard drive might be mounted in Read Only mode.  From a terminal window, type in `mount` and check for what `/` is mounted as.

```
root@terrance-Compaq:/etc/X11# mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
```

after the type you should see the `(rw,errors=remount-ro)`, if not, remount the root partition as Read / Write by typing in the following at the terminal window:

`sudo mount -o remount,rw /`

then try to modify your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

**NOTE:** Recovery mode is always mounted Read Only.  Before making any modifications in Recovery Mode, type in:

`mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: I tried" mount |  grep errors" and found "/dev/sdb2 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)". but I tried "sudo mount -o remount, rw /" same thing...

Comment: @Hiwasawa that shows that your drive is mounted in Read / Write mode, and using sudo, you should be able to modify the files.  Have you tried checking your drive for errors?  Reboot to Recovery Mode and choose `fsck` from the menu, and check your drives for errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you boot in recovery mode or **Black Screen** as you said, your entire root partition is mounted as `read-only`. To remount it as `read-write` use the following command.

`mount -o rw,remount /`

After this command, you can edit your `conf` file.

---

**Note:**

You don't need to write `sudo` as you are already logged in as root.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming that these commands give you read only access

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo vi /et/X11/xorg.conf
```

And that you can't become root with

```
su
```

I'm wondering whether it is possible to

```
sudo mv xorg.conf xorg-old.conf
sudo touch xorg.conf
xclip -sel clip xorg-old.conf # copy file to clipboard
sudo vi xorg.conf # paste xorg-old.conf into the file and try to edit
```

Otherwise you might be able to change the permissions of the file

```
sudo chmod 744 /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Comment: `sudo chmod 755 /etc/X11/xorg.conf` should be done in very rare cases, please add that permissions should be changed back to 744 after doing that! Then I'll remove my -1! Welcome to ASKUbuntu anyways !